# Generate create table DDL from any arbitrary select query?

Tags: oracle, ddl

Using allroundautomations PL/SQL Developer, is there a way, given any arbitrary select query like this:

```
select myfavoritenum, myfavoritetxt 
from tablewithmanycolumns
```

to magically receive a create table statement:

```
create table justmyfavorites (
    myfavoritenum number,
    myfavoritetxt varchar2(30)
)
```

I'm aware of `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`, but I don't necessarily want to create the table right then, or in that particular database, etc.

Attempting to Google up a solution, I also became aware of `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL`, but that appears to be for existing objects, not arbitrary queries.

Comment: This topic was closed even though I was looking exactly for a reply to that question, so much for "unlikely to help other users"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this, using Java, would be to prepare the query statement, then use the `PreparedStatement.getMetaData()` method to obtain the [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/ResultSet.html) object that has the list of columns that would be returned, as well as their data types.

Other database interfaces, such as ODBC and OCI, have similar functionality.

Comment: I'm using ODP.NET, and yeah, it looks like if you get an OracleDataReader object by executing a query, you can use the reader's GetSchemaTable() to find this. The Oracle datatypes are returned as numbers from an enum, which I can munge into text with a case statement. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#i1006262